# too Adj to do something

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is a common sentence pattern, but I met several variants that I am not sure if they expressing the same meaning. As far as I knew, ***too adj to do something*** means they dont want to do this thing, but ***too adj just to do something*** means they want to do. But when I was meeting this one ***you are never too cool to learn new things***, I got lost.

Comment: You could be *too weak to speak* even if you really wanted to speak. It's completely context-dependent whether someone who's *too X to Y* actually ***wants*** to do Y - all it means is that they ***can't*** do it (because they are ***too Y***, whatever ***Y*** happens to be). If you are *too X **just** to do Y* that simply means that (regardless of whether you actually do it or not) doing ***Y*** is ***not sufficient***.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I think your second note isn't quite accurate.

*John is too funny to go to comedy shows.*  This implies that since John himself is funny, he doesn't go to comedy shows.

*John is too funny to just go to comedy shows.*  This implies that because John is funny, when he goes to a comedy show he maybe gets involved (heckling the comedian, making side jokes, something like that).  For this example to work, the emphasis would have to be on *go*.

*John is too athletic to just go to the gym.*  Again it implies something more than *just* going to the gym.  He shows off, or works harder than most, or something else other than the simple act of being at the gym.

In your final example, *you are never too ____* is usually an argument for doing something.  In this case, *you are never too cool to learn new things* is implying that learning is cool, not some boring thing that cool kids don't do.  *You are never too fit to run a mile* might imply that no matter how good of shape you're in, even if you run marathons, sometimes just running a mile is a good workout.